# How to customize KendoUI theme if i'm using KendoUI ASP MVC Complete

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to set the theme of my kendo bar chart to "metro" theme but can't seems to do it unless i explicitly declare it in my razor code.

I'm expecting the code below to work but somehow the rendered bar chart use the default theme.

```
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/styles/kendo.metro.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/styles/kendo.dataviz.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/styles/kendo.dataviz.metro.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">  
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/js/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"></script>

<section id="content">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        @RenderBody()
        @(Html.Kendo().Chart()
            .Name("chart")
            .Title("Internet Users")
            .Series(series => {
                series.Bar(new double[] { 15.7, 16.7, 20, 23.5, 26.6 }).Name("World");
                series.Bar(new double[] { 67.96, 68.93, 75, 74, 78 }).Name("United States");
            })
            .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                .Categories("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009")
            )
            .ValueAxis(axis => axis
                .Numeric().Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0}%"))
            )
            .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                .Visible(true)
                .Format("{0}%")
            )
        )   
    </div>        
</section>
```

but this works.

```
            @(Html.Kendo().Chart()
            .Name("chart")
            .Title("Internet Users")
            .Series(series => {
                series.Bar(new double[] { 15.7, 16.7, 20, 23.5, 26.6 }).Name("World");
                series.Bar(new double[] { 67.96, 68.93, 75, 74, 78 }).Name("United States");
            })
            .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                .Categories("2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009")
            )
            .ValueAxis(axis => axis
                .Numeric().Labels(labels => labels.Format("{0}%"))
            )
            .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
                .Visible(true)
                .Format("{0}%")
            )
            .Theme("metro")
        )
```